# How to install iOS 8.0.2 on simulator?

Tags: ios, iphone

I got an app that got reports for crash and issues from the iOS 8.0.2.

Is there's a way to install iOS 8.0.2 on simulator for testing?

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ you can download old versions of Xcode. I think version 6.2 or 6.3 might come with the iOS 8.0 simulator – just search for "Xcode 6.2"

Answer (score 1):

While `Xcode` itself only is bundled with the simulators for the latest two iOS releases, you still can import older releases:

1. Download old version of Xcode [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) for `iOS8` you need `Xcode 6.0`
2. Mount the Downloaded `.dmg`
3. Right-click the `Xcode.app` to *“Show Package Contents.”*
4. Navigate to: `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer`
5. copied `iPhoneSimulatorX.Y.sdk` over to the same location in `/Applications/Xcode.app`
6. relaunching `Xcode`